# SQL Filter query if column has more than one distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a query that returns `Date` `Username` and `Download Count` of a user if download counts exceeds `2`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]) 'Date', 
       actionby                  AS 'Username', 
       Count(*)                  'Download Count' 
FROM   [dbo].[log] 
WHERE  actiontaken = 'Download' 
       AND type = 'Document' 
       AND CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]) BETWEEN 
           CONVERT(DATE, 
           '" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
           AND 
CONVERT(DATE, '" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]), 
          actionby 
HAVING Count(*) > 1 
ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```

Below is the returned table

```
+------------+----------+----------------+
|    Date    | Username | Download Count |
+------------+----------+----------------+
| 01/01/2018 | Jane     |              3 |
+------------+----------+----------------+
```

`Jane` did 3 downloads.

But 2 of them are the same file (identified by `fileNumber`).

How can I change my query so that it will not add in duplicated downloads of any `fileNumber` on that date?

e.g. Jane downloaded `file1` once, and `file2` twice. `Download Count` will count `2` instead of `3`.

Thank you

---

**EDIT**: After implementing @salman-a's answer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [datetime])  'Date', 
       actionby                   'Username', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT filenumber) 'Download Count' 
FROM   [dbo].[log] 
WHERE  actiontaken = 'Download' 
       AND type = 'Document' 
       AND CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]) BETWEEN 
           CONVERT(DATE, 
           '" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
           AND 
CONVERT(DATE, '" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]), 
          actionby
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT filenumber) > 1 
ORDER  BY COUNT(DISTINCT filenumber) DESC
```

Let me know if I misunderstood it. Thank you.

Comment: You could change `HAVING Count(*) > 1 ` to `HAVING Count(distinct fileNumber) > 1` to do a count of the different file numbers for each group.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: You better add this as an answer, because both current answers are wrong :-)

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth / there's now an answer with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53152809/361842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT fileNumber)` in all three places.

Comment: I edited my question to add in the query after implementing your answer :)

Comment: I replaced all `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT filenumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `fileNumber` column in `group by` and select list

```
select [date],Username,[Download Count] 
from
(SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]) 'Date', 
           actionby                  AS 'Username', 
           filenumber, 
           Count(*)                  'Download Count' 
    FROM   [dbo].[log] 
    WHERE  actiontaken = 'Download' 
           AND type = 'Document' 
           AND CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]) BETWEEN 
               CONVERT(DATE, 
               '" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
               AND 
    CONVERT(DATE, '" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
    GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, [datetime]), 
              actionby, 
              filenumber )X
   where [Download Count]>1 
    ORDER  BY [Download Count] DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. So I need to add in `filenumber` in my `SELECT`, and `GROUP BY` statements, am I right?

Comment: This does not answer the question, it returns filenumbers downloaded more than once.

Comment: This will simply add more noise to the result... data that OP probably does not want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, by selecting the distinct of desired columns in a derived table you can get the desired granular level.

```
SELECT Date, ActionBy AS 'Username', COUNT(*) 'Download Count' 

( SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) 'Date',FileNumber,ActionBy,ActionTaken,Type 
FROM [dbo].[Log])a 

WHERE ActionTaken = 'Download' and Type = 'Document' and CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) 

BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
and CONVERT(date,'" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 

GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [DateTime]), ActionBy 

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, two different timestamps on the same day will be Distinct (need to Cast in the Distinct Select or simply apply Distinct in COUNT)